# Jetpack Compose BasicTextField with ellipsis at the end

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In my project I need to show 2 text inputs for entering money amount. When user enters one input other will show converted value in other currency. I need to show long text in BasicTextField with ellipsis.

```
    var focused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var textState by remember(state.amount) {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
    }


    if (!amountsEqual(state.amount.toBigDecimalOrNull(), textState.text.toBigDecimalOrNull())) {
        if (!state.dimAmount || state.amount.isNotEmpty()) {
            val text = if (!focused) state.amount.shortedBy(17) else state.amount
            textState = textState.copy(text = text, selection = TextRange(text.length))
        }
    }

    val textColor = when {
        state.dimAmount -> Colors.grey50
        else -> Colors.leah
    }

BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                    focused = focusState.isFocused
                    onFocusChanged?.invoke(focusState.isFocused)
                }
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            value = textState,
            enabled = state.amountEnabled,
            singleLine = true,
            onValueChange = { textFieldValue ->
                if (isValid(textFieldValue.text, state.validDecimals)) {
                    textState = textFieldValue
                    onChangeAmount.invoke(textFieldValue.text)
                }
            },
            textStyle = ColoredTextStyle(
                color = textColor,
                textStyle = ComposeAppTheme.typography.headline1,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            ),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                ) {
                    if (textState.text.isEmpty()) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            text = state.primaryPrefix ?: "0",
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            maxLines = 1,
                            color = ComposeAppTheme.colors.grey,
                            style = ComposeAppTheme.typography.headline1,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                        )
                    }
                    innerTextField()
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: BasicTextField not supporting overflow the TextField does. And for my code I need to format BasicTextField to show Ellipsis at the end when its too long to fit screen.

Comment: I don't see support for text-overflow in TextField as well .

Comment: Sorry not TextField, but BasicText. In my project I have two inputs. And while one has focus, other input should behave like Text with overflow.